# Insert image from iOS app into Windows Azure Container?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, azure

I want to insert images into Windows Azure container from my iOS app, but I couldn't get this working. I have created a container named aieimagecontainer in Windows Azure.

I am able to insert into other SQL tables in Windows Azure using below code.

```
MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://xxxxxxxxxx.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];


    NSDictionary *item = @{ @"latitude" : latitude, @"longitude" : longitude, @"speed" : speed, @"channel" : [deviceIDs objectAtIndex:notificationcounter], @"message" : @"Notification from iOS MapApp", @"truck_number" : @"T201" };

    MSTable *smart_truck_incidentTable = [client tableWithName:@"smart_truck_incident"];
    [smart_truck_incidentTable insert:item completion:^(NSDictionary *insertedItem, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Item inserted, id: %@", [insertedItem objectForKey:@"id"]);
         }
     }];
```

I tried to reuse this code by changing clientWithApplicationURLString and applicationKey values to storage account values. But the insert simply not working.

Can anyone point me to some sample code or reference? Or any other better suggestions to store images in Windows Azure is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought of sharing if anyone else is looking for the same. Download iOS code from http://www.files.com/shared/51f622c62ba2f/BlobExample.zip. Update credentials in ViewController.m with your storage name and access key.

Comment: I personally don't recommend this. It's pretty old code and will not work to new iOS.